# Should edit requests removing tag link from any question approved?

Tags: discussion

I just came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60489448/9134576) question.

In the first line, C is tagged as [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), I believe that this adds no additional information what so ever. So I'm not sure whether the edits that remove this tag should be approved or not?

This is not useful as when we hover over it, it does not shows us information regarding C language as it does at the bottom of any question. And after clicking on it we are redirected to the list of questions tagged with C, which I don't think is the intention of the person adding it.

The dilemma is there because there is no harm of it being there either, which makes me unsure about it.

---

> [image]

Comment: But... no one suggested any edit to remove that right? And you have full-edit privileges, so you need no approval? Maybe what you want to ask if that should be removed or not, not if the edit should be approved?

Comment: @yivi, No, no one suggested that yet. (Not occurred to me, atleast) Actually I want both of those questions answered. But I thought, getting answer on any one will be enough for me.

Comment: I don't see any reason to remove it. It's not noise, and from simply a text point of view, there's no difference between "I hit some C" and "I hit some [tag:c]", so why remove it? It's trivial at best.

Comment: @Larnu I'd argue that it *is* noise. It's linking to a bunch of unrelated questions about C. With that said, I'm not confident that's really enough to warrant removal. Were I to make a large scale re-write of the question, I'd probably drop the link. But if it's something smaller like fixing typos or re-phrasing a section, I likely wouldn't. And I don't think I'd make an edit *just* to remove the link - seems a bit pointless, since it's not that big of an issue. However, I wouldn't like many questions to have "I have this `[tag:some-language]` code..." - we *already know* which tag it is.

Comment: IMO it `is` as annoying and distracting as edits that add `code` ticks `to` every word that relates to `computers`. Linked tags are at the bottom. (Well – or at the top, in the mobile view.)

Comment: And now I half-expected that link after it to code to point to [a useful explanation](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_code). The link should span the full "code from [the] Linux kernel", so it is immediately clear what it points to.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this type of edit is not useful on its own (especially for old posts).

My recommendations:

- Unless you find anything else to edit in the particular post, let it be as tag.
- If that edit is done as the only change by a user without full editing privileges - reject the change.
- Absolutely do not start an editing spree to remove tags from the body of posts.
- If a post on the main site has excessive (more than one) use of tags or totally invalid tags - feel free to edit them out.

Personally, I see no reason to have "tag:" formatting inside the post (with the exception of some questions on meta). There is almost no way a link to "all questions for ... tag" would give any additional context to the question.

On the other hand, for a single tag named exactly as its written in your question, I don't have any problem reading such posts.